# How to use trio_asyncio with legacy sync code in python

Tags: python, python-trio

I have legacy python application which is synchronous.
I started to use async code inside this application in this way (simplified):

```py
async def loader():
  async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    # some async tasks started here
    await trio.to_thread.run_sync(legacyCode)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
  trio.run(loader)
```

Inside `legacyCode` I can use `trio.from_thread.run(asyncMethod)` to run some async code from the legacy synchronous code.
It works well, but now I need to include new library (`triopg`) which use internally `trio_asyncio`.

So I need to modify the way how I start my application - I need to replace `trio.run` by `trio_asyncio.run`. That's easy but after the `trio.to_thread` -> `trio.from_thread` the async code does not work because trio_asyncio has no loop defined.

Here is a short demonstration:

```py
import trio
import trio_asyncio

def main():
  trio.from_thread.run(amain)

async def amain():
  print(f"Loop in amain: {trio_asyncio.current_loop.get()}")  # this print none

async def loader():
  print(f"Loop in loader: {trio_asyncio.current_loop.get()}")  # this print some loop
  await trio.to_thread.run_sync(main)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  trio_asyncio.run(loader)
```

How should I modify the example above so the trio_asyncio is able to found the loop inside `amain()` function?
Or is this approach completely wrong? If so, how can I use small pieces of async code inside huge synchronous application when libraries needs to use `trio` and `trio_asyncio`?

I use python 3.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution and ... it seems to be easy :-)

The `trio_asyncio` loop needs to be opened manually when we call the async function from thread. So the only difference is to add `open_loop()` call in `amain()` function:

```py
import trio
import trio_asyncio


def main():
  trio.from_thread.run(amain)


async def amain():
  async with trio_asyncio.open_loop():
    print(f"Loop in amain: {trio_asyncio.current_loop.get()}")  # this print another loop


async def loader():
  print(f"Loop in loader: {trio_asyncio.current_loop.get()}")  # this print one loop
  await trio.to_thread.run_sync(main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  trio_asyncio.run(loader)
```